# How to fix the error that "input tensor must have rank 4"?

Tags: keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, lstm

```
X_train shape :  (13973, 100, 6, 5) 
X_test shape :  (3494, 100, 6, 5) 
y_train shape :  (13973, 6, 5) 
Y_test shape :  (3494, 6, 5)
```

Code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32,5,5,input_shape=(100,6,5))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4,4))))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(5)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss="mse",optimizer="adam")
```

Getting the error of

> input tensor must have rank 4?

Comment: The input to Conv2D should have rank 4, but one of your dimension is considered as the timesteps dimension by the TimeDistributed, so you should give your network an input with rank 5

Comment: 6x5 is the shape of your data/image and 100 is the time-steps?

Comment: @SaTa Yes,6x5 is the shape of your data/image and 100 is the time-steps.

Comment: Reshape your input into (13973, 100, 6, 5, 1). Last dimension here would be the channels in the 'images'. Conv2D expects 3d input.